# Call Fragment2 for result from Fragment1

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onactivityresult

I have a base Activity in which I have 2 fragments (lets say Fragment1 & Fragment2)
I need to call Fragment2 from Fragment1 for capturing data and then use the same in Fragment1 .

I know the that call of Activity for result can be fetched inside onActivityResult of baseActivity but how will I call the Fragment2 from Fragment1 for result purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without MVVM**

The simplest built in way i guess is using `Fragment.setTargetFragment(@Nullable Fragment fragment, int requestCode)`

from fragment 1:

```
val fragment = Fragment2.newInstane()
fragment.setTargetFragment(this, 10)
```

from fragment 2 when you wanna get result back tofragment 1:

```
fun setResultBack(){
    val intent = Intent()
    // inject anything to intent here
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(10, Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    fragmentManager.popBackStack()
}
```

finally override `onActivityResult` from fragment 1:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if(requestCode == 10){
        // handle result here
    } 
    else super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

And this works in all cases even after restoring fragment state or after configuration change.

**with MVVM**

Use a shared view model as recommanded from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get the hint from this solution. Because I cant write code for your requirement, but this will give you an idea, what you can do.

```
public class Fragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof ActivityHome) {
            ((ActivityHome) context).setFragment1(this);
        }
    }
}

public class ActivityHome extends AppCompatActivity {
    Fragment1 fragment1;

    public void setFragment1(Fragment1 fragment1) {
        this.fragment1 = fragment1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (fragment1 != null) fragment1.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Even you can implement this by using interfaces, but I'll suggest you [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) as this is tiny library, which makes communication very easy.

(1) Make Data Class

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

(2) Subscribe for Event

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

(3) Register & Unregister

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

and Trigger from anywhere

```
 EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Comment: Your answer basically tells me what I should do when I get it from another Activity not from another Fragment . How should I call Fragment2  for Result in this case from Fragment1

Comment: I did not show you that way, I wanted to show, that you can hold instance of Fragment2 in Activity also, and do anything you want.

Comment: But how can I call Fragment2 from Fragment1 in this case ? , I want to use Fragment2 result inside Fragment1

Comment: You will just fire an event from Fragment1 and get that in Fragment2 in `onMessageEvent`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at this tight coupling and refactoring so the fragments aren't so tightly coupled and the data fetch is similarly decoupled.  Have a look at the various resources on MVP, MVC, or MVVP for the concept.

Sometimes, though, you do need to have one fragment's info conveyed to another.  The typical/recommended way of doing this is to define a "fragment callback" interface that your fragments require and that interface is implemented by your `Activity`.  So the `Activity` is the medium for communication (which helps with decoupling the fragments.)  You can use a custom base class for your fragments so they have a common definition of the interface.

```
public class MyBaseFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface FragmentCallbacks {
        //  Use whatever arguments you may require here
        void fetchData();
    }

    protected FragmentCallbacks  mCallbacks;

    @Override
    void onAttach(Context context) {
        try {
            mCallbacks = (FragmentCallbacks)context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Activity must implement FragmentCallbacks");
        }
    }
}
```

Now in `Fragment1` you can call `mCallbacks.fetchData()` which the `Activity` can use to call into a public method you create in `Fragment2`.  When it gets the data back (probably async), it can then provide it to `Fragment1` via a public method you create.